# Index value is also shown with database value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have dropdown with database values.But,dropdown also shows database value's index and i want to remove index.I have searched in google and other forums,but not getting expected solution.

```
function products_edit($product_id) {
    $this->load->helper('form');  
    $this->load->helper('html');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('products_model');
    $data=$this->products_model->general();
    $category['categories']=$this->products_model->get_category();
    $product = $this->products_model->get_product($product_id);

    $this->data['title'] = 'Edit Product';

    //validate form input
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Product name', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Product Description', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('category', 'Category', 'required|xss_clean');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('extras', 'Extras', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('price', 'Price', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('is_featured', 'Is Featured', 'required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('prorder', 'prorder', 'required|xss_clean');

    if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {      
        $data = array(
            'product_name'=> $this->input->post('name'),
            'product_desc'=> $this->input->post('description'),
            'product_category' => $this->input->post('category'),
            'extras' => $this->input->post('extras'),
            'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
            'is_featured' => $this->input->post('is_featured'),
            'prorder' => $this->input->post('prorder'),
        );

        if ($this->form_validation->run() === true) {
            $this->products_model->updateproducts($product_id, $data);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "<p>Product updated successfully.</p>");

            redirect('products_controller/products_edit/'.$product_id);
        }           
    }

    $this->data['message'] = (validation_errors() ? validation_errors() : $this->session->flashdata('message'));

    $this->data['product'] = $product;

    //display the edit product form
    $this->data['name'] = array(
        'name'      => 'name',
        'id'        => 'name',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'style'     => 'width:300px;',
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('name', $product['product_name']),
    );

    $this->data['description'] = array(
        'name'      => 'description',
        'id'        => 'description',
        'type'      => 'text',
        'cols'      =>  60,
        'rows'      =>  5,
        'value'     => $this->form_validation->set_value('description', $product['product_desc']),
    );

    $cat=array();
    $test = array();
    for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++) {
        $test[$i] = array($category['categories'][$i] => $category['categories'][$i]);
    } 

    $this->data['category'] = $test;

    $this->data['extras'] = array(
        'name'  => 'extras',
        'id'    => 'extras',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'style' => 'width:250px;',
        'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('extras', $product['extras']),
        );

    $this->data['price'] = array(
        'name'  => 'price',
        'id'    => 'picture',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'style' => 'width:250px;',
        'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('price', $product['price']),
    );

    $this->data['is_featured'] = array(
        'name'  => 'is_featured',
        'id'    => 'is_featured',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'style' => 'width:250px;',
        'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('is_featured', $product['is_featured']),
    );

    $this->data['prorder'] = array(
        'name'  => 'prorder',
        'id'    => 'prorder',
        'type'  => 'text',
        'style' => 'width:250px;',
        'value' => $this->form_validation->set_value('prorder', $product['prorder']),
    );

    $this->load->view('products_edit', $this->data);
}
```

The error occurs in this line.

```
for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++) {
    $test[$i] = array($category['categories'][$i] => $category['categories'][$i]);
}
```

The error is due to `$i` in the test array. If I remove it, causing an error. I don't have solution for this error.

The screen shot http://i.share.pho.to/f4a24cc3_o.png

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason why you're using a for loop to build your categories dropdown list?

The `$test` array needs to look something like this:

```
$test = array(
    1 => 'Pizza',
    2 => 'Sandwich',
    3 => 'Dessert',
    4 => 'Salad'
);
```

Where the key is the associated id to the category and the value is the category name. At the minute you are loading both the key and value of the array with the **whole** category (based on it's index).

If you are wanting to pull out all the categories into a dropdown box, I would suggest something similar to the below, as this would allow you to add additional categories in future and them appear in the dropdown box:

```
foreach($category['categories'] as $category) {
    $test[$category['id']] = $category['name'];
}
$this->data['category'] = $test;
```

This would require the categories (which I assume are being pulled out of a database table?) to have an `id` and `name` field.

Hope that helps...